# My xstrcmp (which is copy of strcmp library function) gives incorrect results

Tags: c

The compiler gives no error but I am not getting desired output of self made strcmp function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
    
    int main() {
    char str1[20],str2[20];
    gets(str1);
    gets(str2);
    printf("\n%d",xstrcmp(str1,str2));
        return 0;
    }
    int xstrcmp(char *p1,char *p2){
         int k;
        while(*p1!='\0'||*p2!='\0'){
            if((*p1-*p2)==0){
                p1++,p2++;
                continue;
            }
            else{
               
               k= ((*p1)-(*p2));
            }
        }
        return k;
    }
```

Comment: The compiler *should* warn about implicitly declared `xstrcmp`. Try turning up compiler warnings. Then either add a forward declaration, or simply move the function to be defined before you call it.

Comment: do not use `gets`, but if you do, realize that everybody will tell you "don't use gets", and at least make the buffers much larger, like 1000 characters.

Comment: @hyde I agree that this is a good thing. However, in this case, the C compiler will assume `xstrcmp` is a function return `int` (which it actually is) and "deduce" the two arguments correctly as `char*`.

Comment: You also need to give `k` an initial value (which will be returned if the loop completes without finding a mismatch). Presumably, that value will be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, please read this: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/10871073). So, instead of your `gets(str1)` line, use `fgets(str1, 20, stdin)` (and likewise for reading `str2`). Second, you should really provide a prototype (pre-declaration) of your `xstrcmp` before using it; a line like this before `main` will do: `int xstrcmp(char* p1, char* p2);` (or you could move the whole body of that function to before main). In your case, as the compiler will assume that it is a function returning an `int`, there is no major issue; but it's bad practice to use such undeclared functions and (IIRC), the option is planned for removal in a future C Standard.

Now to the logic problems in your function: There are two.

1. You don't give `k` *any* value that will be used if the `while` loop finished without finding a mismatch (i.e., if the passed strings are the same);  this is a simple fix: initialize `k` to zero, like `int k = 0;`.
2. When you *do* find a mismatch, you neither increment the `p1` and `p2` pointers, and nor do you break out of the `while` loop – so that loop will continue forever, once such a mismatch is found. To fix this, simply add a `break;` statement in your `else` block.

Here is a working version of your code that addresses these issues:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int xstrcmp(char* p1, char* p2); // Pre-declaration of the function

int main() {
    char str1[20], str2[20];
    fgets(str1, 20, stdin);
    fgets(str2, 20, stdin);
    printf("\n%d", xstrcmp(str1, str2));
    return 0;
}

int xstrcmp(char* p1, char* p2) {
    int k = 0; // We need to give k a value to use if we complete the loop without a mismatch
    while (*p1 != '\0' || *p2 != '\0') {
        if ((*p1 - *p2) == 0) {
            p1++, p2++;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            k = ((*p1) - (*p2));
            break; // Once we find a mismatch, we must terminate the loop after assiging k
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

---

Note: it is more conventional to use a loop condition like `while (*p1 != '\0' && *p2 != '\0')` (using `&&` instead of `||`). However, in your case, the internal loop logic (once corrected) will allow either to work: any mismatch will stop (`break`) the loop and, if the strings are the same, then both `p1` and `p2` will point to `nul` characters at the same time, so the test using `||` will still fail when it is expected to.